# Returning all elements from a Map[List()] in Scala

Tags: list, scala, function, dictionary, return

I'm VERY new to Scala so apologies if anything sounds a bit basic. Working on a uni assignment and can't seem to find any similar questions around.

EDIT: The idea of this function is that I pass through a string of data and separate it up into individual elements. From what I can tell, things are being separated correctly with the lists holding the correct data types and correct information.

So I've created a function that returns a Map[String, List[(Int, String, Float)]]

The function does other things, but to keep it short, once I've build the list this is how I build the map and return it: -

```
val newMap = Map(name -> newList2.toList)

newMap
```

I can newMap.foreach to cycle through the map and find all of my elements. This works as expected: -

```
(Sample Key,List((3,PlaceName1,2.7)))
(Sample Key,List((2,PlaceName1,3.8)))
(Sample Key,List((1,PlaceName1,0.75)))
```

I am simply trying to call this function and save the map into a new variable. I have tried this two ways: -

```
val saveMap = separator("1:PlaceName1:0.75,2:PlaceName2:3.8,3:PlaceName3:2.7")
```

However when I try to cycle through this, I only get the first list element: -

```
(Sample Key,List((1,PlaceName1,0.75)))
```

I have also tried to use a mapBuffer in the format of: -

```
var mapBuffer: Map[String, List[(Int, String, Float)]] = Map()

mapBuffer = separator("1:PlaceName1:0.75,2:PlaceName2:3.8,3:PlaceName3:2.7")
```

Again, all I get as my return here is: -

```
mutated mapBuffer


(Sample Key,List((1,PlaceName1,0.75)))
```

Being new to Scala but with some experience in Java and C#, it's killing me how I'm returning a Map value, saving it into a map value that is built the same, and it's not coming through. Tried every iteration of maps and lists I could find and can't find anything on this from searching.

Is anyone able to offer any assistance?

EDIT:

Here is the whole code for the function and how I am attempting to call it.

```
    def separator(data:String): Map[String, List[(Int, String, Float)]] = {
  //Route name will be worked out later. For now, this is a sample.
  val sampleRouteName = "First Route"

  //Stage list will hold each list entry
  val stageList = ListBuffer[(Int, String, Float)]()

  //Stage list builder will put all the list entries together
  var stageListBuilder = List[(Int, String, Float)]()

  if (data.contains(",")) {
    //Find index of first comma
    val commaIndex = data.indexOf(",")

    //Split everything before the comma off
    val (firstEntry, restOfPhrase) = data.splitAt(commaIndex)

    //Find the index of the colon in the first entry
    val colonIndex = firstEntry.indexOf(":")

    //Split everything before the colon off to just keep the number
    val (number, restOfStage) = firstEntry.splitAt(colonIndex)

    //Get rid of the first colon from the rest of the line
    val restOfStage2 = restOfStage.replaceFirst(":", "")

    //Find the index of the next colon
    val colonIndex2 = restOfStage2.indexOf(":")

    //Split everything before the colon off to just keep the stage name
    val (stageName, restOfStage3) = restOfStage2.splitAt(colonIndex2)

    //Get rid of the colon leaving just the stage length
    val stageLength = restOfStage3.replaceFirst(":", "")

    //Put all of these together into a list line in the builder
    stageListBuilder = List((number.toInt,stageName,stageLength.toFloat))

    //Add the list line from the builder to the list as an element
    stageListBuilder.foreach(line => stageList += line)

    //Call recursive function and remove the comma from the start
    separator(restOfPhrase.replaceFirst(",", ""))
  }
  else if (data.length != 0) {
    //Find index of first colon
    val colonIndex = data.indexOf(":")

    //Split everything before the colon off to just keep the number
    val (number, restOfStage) = data.splitAt(colonIndex)

    //Get rid of the first colon from the rest of the line
    val restOfStage2 = restOfStage.replaceFirst(":", "")

    //Find the index of the next colon
    val colonIndex2 = restOfStage2.indexOf(":")

    //Split everything before the colon off to just keep the stage name
    val (stageName, restOfStage3) = restOfStage2.splitAt(colonIndex2)

    //Get rid of the colon leaving just the stage length
    val stageLength = restOfStage3.replaceFirst(":", "")

    //Put all of these together into a list line in the builder
    stageListBuilder = List((number.toInt,stageName,stageLength.toFloat))

    //Add the list line from the builder to the list as an element
    stageListBuilder.foreach(line => stageList += line)
  }

  //This is a map that accurately contains the key (ie. GCU Route) and a list of the routes.
  val routeMap = Map(sampleRouteName -> stageList.toList)

  //To test that the list has all the elements (CURRENTLY WORKING)
  routeMap.foreach(line => println("TEST - " + line))

  //Return the map
  routeMap
}

//val saveMap = separator("1:City Chambers:0.75,2:Velodrome:3.8,3:People's Palace:2.7")

//Create new map buffer
var mapBuffer: Map[String, List[(Int, String, Float)]] = Map()

//Call separator function
mapBuffer = separator("1:City Chambers:0.75,2:Velodrome:3.8,3:People's Palace:2.7")

//Test that each element is in the list (CURRENTLY NOT WORKING)
mapBuffer.foreach(line => println(line))
```

Comment: So how is `separator` implemented? Seems to me like the error is in that function.

Comment: I doubt the problem is how you are calling `separator` but the implementation of `separator` itself. Describe to us what it should do and show us the code you tried.

Comment: Alright bit harder to write stuff nicely in this box. In short, the separator function takes a string and divides it up based on characters. So the string "1:PlaceName1:0.75,2:PlaceName2:3.8" becomes List((Int, String, Float)) with each element being (1, PlaceName1, 0.7) and (2, PlaceName2, 3.8)

Comment: _"From what I can tell, things are being separated correctly with the lists holding the correct data types and correct information."_ - for what I can tell it is not, since the results are wrong. Just paste the code.

Comment: CONTINUING FROM THE POST ABOVE...

These are then stored into a map with a key. For now I am just manually adding the key "Sample Key" which I will fix up later. From cycling through the map, it does appear that there are multiple elements saved to the key so from my view, it seems that this is correct. Saving this map outside of the function however appears to be where only one element is saved.

Comment: Okay I'll paste the whole thing in @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: The one that works isn't really working, you see all lines because you are calling a recursive method. But you are never using the results of the previous iteration in the new one. In the end, your function always just creates a map of just one key and one value. Also, you believe `stageListBuilder` is containing multiple elements, but it is not.

Comment: Ah right got you. So I'm just printing an individual line, then calling the recursive method and printing the next one. Got you. Leaves me like "Damn, now everything doesn't really work out" haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned you are using same keys as a key of a Map. Let's imagine we have separator method like this:

```
val str = "1:PlaceName1:0.75,2:PlaceName2:3.8,3:PlaceName3:2.7"

def separator(str: String): List[(String, (Int, String, Float))] =
  str.split(",").map(_.split(":")).toList.map(_.toList).collect {
    case ii :: s :: d :: Nil =>
      "Sample Key" -> (ii.toInt, s, d.toFloat)
  }


separator(str).foearch(println)
// result:
(Sample Key,(1,PlaceName1,0.75))
(Sample Key,(2,PlaceName2,3.8))
(Sample Key,(3,PlaceName3,2.7))
```

if we convert our result to a Map we lose some elements with same key in this case Sample Key:

```
def separator1(str: String): Map[String, List[(Int, String, Float)]] =
  str.split(",").map(_.split(":")).toList.map(_.toList).collect {
    case ii :: s :: d :: Nil =>
      "Sample Key" -> List((ii.toInt, s, d.toFloat))
  }.toMap

separator1(str).foreach(println)
// result:
// (Sample Key,List((3,PlaceName3,2.7)))
```

So we cannot have the same keys as KEY of a Map. The KEYs of a Map should be a unique.

```
case class Aname(a: Int, b: String, c: Float)

def separator2(str: String): Map[String, List[Aname]] =
  str.split(",").map(_.split(":")).toList.map(_.toList).collect {
    case ii :: s :: d :: Nil =>
      Aname(ii.toInt, s, d.toFloat)
  }.groupBy(_.b)

separator2(str).foreach(println)

// result:
// (PlaceName3,List(Aname(3,PlaceName3,2.7)))
// (PlaceName2,List(Aname(2,PlaceName2,3.8)))
// (PlaceName1,List(Aname(1,PlaceName1,0.75)))
```

You can play with it [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Bunyod/lqLuNKA0T8KxXDCfOJJQ0g/19)

Comment: Ah got you. Unfortunately the instructions are to create this using the Map[String, List[(Int, String, Float)]] structure. So would I try to build this using the Int, String, Float format as a series of tuples? I'm just kind of saying words I don't know but I could look into those after.

Comment: If you are satified with my answer you can accept it. You can read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: You can use case classes like this `case class Aname(a: Int, B: String, C: Float)`  instead of Tuple

Comment: I've updated my example with case class usage, you can find here https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Bunyod/lqLuNKA0T8KxXDCfOJJQ0g/20